# c# Pregunta sobre if con múltiples condiciones

Tags: c#

soy nuevo en esto del coding y pues se he estado aprendiendo c# solo utilizando tutoriales de Internet y foros.

entonces mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de hacer el siguiente codigo funcione.

```
string test = "hola";
string test1 = "hola";
string test2 = "hola";
if (test1, test1, test2 == "hola")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Todos son hola");
}
```

en vez de poner

```
string test = "hola";
string test1 = "hola";
string test2 = "hola";
if (test1 == "hola" && test1 == "hola" && test2 == "hola")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Todos son hola");
}
```

Comment: hasta donde se no amigo, pues por cada variable que le pases al if debes verificar que se cumpla o no una condición; en este caso poner los parámetros separados por coma te dará un valor de invalid argument

Comment: Esa forma que planteas en el uso del if no existe, es correcta la segunda opcion que planteas

Comment: Para el ejemplo que pones no tiene demasiado sentido, pero por ejemplo podrias crear una clase, y en el constructor haces una comparacion en la que en caso de ser cierta la comparacion sumas 1 a una variable estatica de la clase, tambien creas otra variable estatica que sume 1 cada vez que se crea una instancia. Luego creas todas las instancias de esa clase que quieras con el texto "hola" y luego comparas si el contador es igual al contador del numero de instancias creadas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como variables separadas no hay manera de hacer lo que propones, ya que estás empezando lo que te propongo es que investigues lo que son arreglos (*arrays*).  Es una manera de manejar múltiples valores como un solo objeto.  Un ejemplo para que te vayas familiarizando como funcionan:

```
string[] valores = new string[3]; // declarar un arreglo con 3 "espacios"

valores[0] = "hola"; // asignar un valor a la primera posición
                     // se comienza a contar desde 0
valores[1] = "hola";
valores[2] = "hola";

bool iguales = true;
for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++) // recorrer el arreglo verificando que todos sean iguales
{
    if (valores[i] != "hola")
    {
        iguales = false;
    }
}

if (iguales)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Todos son hola");
}
```

Esta es la forma más simple y solo es una introducción, existen maneras más avanzadas utilizando objetos del framework como listas genéricas (`List<T>`) pero te recomiendo que primero te familiarices con este concepto que es central en la mayoría de lenguajes de programación.

Te dejo un link de la documentación [Matrices Unidimensionales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays).  Aquí le llaman matrices que es el concepto generalizado pero generalmente encontrarás artículos con el nombre de arreglos.

Comment: oh, gracias, esto estaré la documentación, para dominar los arreglos:3

Comment: ¡Excelente!, Te conviene empezar con los conceptos básicos, hay que gatear antes de correr. Bienvenido al mundo del código.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda:3

Answer (score 8):

La unica forma que se me ocurre es con la ayuda de linq, algo como ser

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>() { test, test1, test2 };

if(temp.All(x=>x=="hola")){
   Console.WriteLine("Todos son hola");
}
```

[Enumerable.All(IEnumerable, Func) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pero... realmente no logro entender nada. el el otro comentario que lo explica con arreglos es mas sencillo.

Comment: pero conoces linq? porque si nunca has usado linq entonces esta claro que nunca vas a entender la solucion que planteo

Comment: la verdad es que si la solucion requiere array dejaria el if que evalue cada valor, queda mucho mas prolijo en el codigo de esa forma que todo el codigo adicional que incluye el array, o al menos usa List<>

Comment: no, no conozco linq:c

Comment: +1. Linq cae perfecto para el problema del OP.

Comment: @Yusuf es normal que no entiendas linq. Para eso se necesita una buena base de C#, en particular saber que son los lambdas.

Comment: bueno luego investigare sobre linq, primero quiero aprender mas sobre las clases y metodos.

Comment: me parece genial, cuando veas el poder de linq te va a encantar

Answer (score 1):

Hola Yusuf aqui te dejo un pequeño codigo utilizando array y linq, en lo cual me base en las respuestas y codigos de Diego y Leandro.

Te dejo el codigo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0MQabY), Revisalo, modificalo y dale run.

Informacion sobre la palabra reservada [params](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        string test = "hola";
        string test1 = "hola";
        string test2 = "hola";

        Console.WriteLine("Usando Array");
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", test, test1, test2));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", test, test1, test2, "hola"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", test, test1, test2, "hola", "aloha"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", "hola", "aloha", "hola", "aloha"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", "hola"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithArray("hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", test, test1, test2));

        Console.WriteLine("Usando Linq");
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", test, test1, test2));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", test, test1, test2, "hola"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", test, test1, test2, "hola", "aloha"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", "hola", "aloha", "hola", "aloha"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", "hola"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.StrAllEqualsWithLinq("hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", "hola", test, test1, test2));
    }

    public bool StrAllEqualsWithArray(string key, params string[] values)
    {
        bool flag = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] != key) 
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return flag;
    }

    public bool StrAllEqualsWithLinq(string key, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.All(val => val == key);
    }
}
```

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias, puedo ver que con linq es mucho mejor, ni siquiera tengo la necesidad de usar un for, ayer estuve viendo información sobre linq pero creo que aun es demasiado avanzado para mi xd, aunque puedo entenderlo, a la ora de leer mi propio código me cuesta xd.